# CSS Responsive banner with oblique shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a background for a banner using css where one side has a color and on the other side has another one with a 45° cut like this

[image: example]

I've been able to recreate the above image except for the drop shadow that doesn't stay in the right position.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code code:

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2962ff;
}

#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #2196f3;
  border-right: 400px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the linked question as the linked one doens't address the box-shadow issue.

A solution to your problem would be to use a pseudo element (:before or :after) instead of your #triangle-topleft div, to set `position: relative;` on your container and then to apply this CSS to your pseudo element.

    `box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #2196f3;
    transform: skew(-45deg);
    left: -50px;`

Comment: Chech this handy gradient generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, it even has some presets that are pritty similar to what you want and it will give you the code for most browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS triangle trick with border can not be used for this, as a shadow will still be applied to the box, and not only to the triangle.

You will have to create a pseudo element, rotate it and THEN apply shadow to it.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

#container:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 200%; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 10px #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Basically you create a rectangle which is larger than the parent, then rotate it and apply a shadow. You can tweak the colors and rotation-degree for your needs

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b5TnZ/2032/

Comment: This is working only for some resolution, to make it responsive have i to write cases with 
`@media screen and (max-width: xxpx) {
...
}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try gradient like below:

```css
#container {
  height: 150px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg,#2962ff 49.8%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 50%, #2196f3 calc(50% + 10px));
  background-color:#2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

And simply replace the deg with `to bottom right` if you want the diagonal result:

```css
#container {
  height: 150px;
  width:50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#2962ff 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 50%, #2196f3 calc(50% + 10px));
  background-color:#2196f3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple color stops in Linear Gradients. Use two color set.

Gradient generated using [Shapy](https://shapy.app)

```css
.canvas {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.gradient-canvas {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(127deg, rgb(31, 163, 209) 0%, rgb(31, 163, 209) 50%, rgb(25, 64, 208) 0%, rgb(46, 101, 223) 52%) 50% 50% / 100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas"><div class="gradient-canvas"></div></div>
```

Comment: there is no shadow here . and why all these divs?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The tilted part is in middle. So I'm creating offset on both sides using another divs

Comment: there is no need, the gradient is enough on a full width div like you can see in my answer .. an your shadow will get broken